# This page can't load Google Maps correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps-sdk-ios

I know much has been said about this topic but I am still a little bit lost.

My google maps is apparently built in the theme because i tried intergeo-maps plugin and also API key for google maps plugins and to no avail in solving this issue.

I read where it say i must generate an API Key and insert into the theme script. I went to wp/admin/functions and I see the following:

```
wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?' . $key, array(), null, true);
```

Where should I put the API Key that i generated?

Comment: Are you sure google-maps-sdk-ios is the tag related to your issue ? Is it anything about iOS?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, can’t you simply add $key = <your key> prior to the snippet you provided?

Answer (score 1):

In your example it is clear that `$key` is a [variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) that API key is stored in it.

So you have two ways to assign your API key to your `$key` variable :

**1-** Hard coding (**Not recommended and may cause issues**)

```
$key="YOUR KEY HERE"; //HERE YOU CAN HARD CODE YOUR API KEY
wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?' . $key, array(), null, true);
```

**2-** Trace `$key` variable and see where `$key` get it's value.I think it should be in your theme setting.You can read your theme documentation for this purpose too.

*PS: For number one , we can't tell you exactly that it can make issues or not because we don't have your full code.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know if i have trace the $key variable as suggested, but i found these keys in the theme/function

Comment: @nameathonadmin So if it helped you, you can choose it as an answer to help others if they had this problem